# For which integer values of n is the matrix diagonalizable by a real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

I need to find the values of n for which matrix C is diagonalizable by a real matrix.

$$ C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
n & n + 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I've calculated the characteristic polynomial $λ^2 - 2λ - λn + 1 = 0$

Which turns to  $λ^2 - λ(2 + n) + 1 = 0$

At this step I'm lost. What do I do afterwards?

Comment: Since you would want it to be diagonalizable by a real matrix, you would want that the quadratic equation you just obtained should have real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Hint The discriminant is $(n+2)^2-4=n(n+4)$

in $(-4,0)$ it is negative the matrix is not a real diagonalizabe.

and if $n<4, n>0$ it is positive, there exists two distinct eigenvalues the matrix is diagonalizabe.

Study the case $n=0,n=4$ when it has a double root

Comment: For n = -4 the eigenvalue is -1, for n = 0 the eigenvalue is 1, but the eigenspaces are both 1-dimensional, so the matrix isn't diagonalizable - am I going in the right direction?

Comment: yes, you are going in the right direction

Comment: so is the answer n < -4 and n > 0?